# SQL database data sort

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting

I am able to get the combined length of first name and last name and order by id.
but i am not able to sort it lexicographically.

```
SELECT CUSTOMER.ID, CUSTOMER.FIRST_NAME, CUSTOMER.LAST_NAME 
FROM CUSTOMER 
WHERE LENGTH(CUSTOMER.FIRST_NAME)+LENGTH(CUSTOMER.LAST_NAME) < 12 
ORDER BY CUSTOMER.ID
```

EXAMPLE

```
ID  first name  last name   combined length of first name and last name
4 - RUTH        HANSON -    10
6 - ANNE        HARRIS -    10
```

but output should be

```
ID  first name  last name   combined length of first name and last name
6 - ANNE        HARRIS -    10
4 - RUTH        HANSON -    10
```

Comment: `order by FIRST_NAME`

Comment: Well, you sort by id. What about sorting by first name, last name instead?

Answer (score 2):

Simply just `order by` FIRST_NAME and then LAST_NAME field

```
SELECT c.ID, c.FIRST_NAME, c.LAST_NAME 
FROM CUSTOMER c
WHERE LENGTH(c.FIRST_NAME)+LENGTH(c.LAST_NAME) < 12 
ORDER BY c.FIRST_NAME, c.LAST_NAME
```

Answer (score 2):

You appear to want to sort lexicographically by first name, followed by last name, so just do that:

```
SELECT
    ID,
    FIRST_NAME,
    LAST_NAME
FROM CUSTOMER
WHERE
    LENGTH(CONCAT(FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME)) < 12
ORDER BY
    FIRST_NAME,
    LAST_NAME;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this by changing the `ORDER BY` as below

```
SELECT C1.ID, C1.FIRST_NAME,C1.LAST_NAME 
FROM CUSTOMER C1
WHERE LENGTH(C1.FIRST_NAME)+LENGTH(C1.LAST_NAME) < 12 
ORDER BY C1.FIRST_NAME ASC, C1.LAST_NAME ASC
```